# multiple Laserscanner for Hector Mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, laserscanner, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to do hector mapping with two sick s300.

They're back to back and with this I have 360° of sight.. so I want to use both laser/scan topics for hector.

How can I tell hector to use two topics?

I already tried the following:

- two Hector Mapping Nodes -> `Result`: I    have two Maps which are jumping
- one Hector Mapping Node and two Laserscanner Nodes -> `Result`: only       using one node
- one Hector Mapping Node and two Laserscanner Nodes one remapped two      the other:   ->`Result`: Laserscan is jumping and building a kind of okay map.. but    not    satisfying cause he is telling    me    that the searchdir angle was to    big    (of course, he thinks I have    one    laserscanner and I am turning    it 180°    degrees)

Is there a better solution to use multiple Laserscanners for hector mapping?

pls help, greez felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215351/multiple-laserscanner-for-hector-mapping/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On thing I think could work definitely, is that you merge both laser scanners into one topic. Problem would be they do not exactly match the origin when they are back to back. So putting it into the laser message format could be a bit annoying.

Maybe this package could be useful for that http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this package for combining two laser scans:
https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools

and if you still have any questions, you can take a look at this video from The Construct:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHWlGy_JhJI&index=36&list=PLK0b4e05LnzbrLrLhOhSvLdaQZOsJl59N

---

Originally posted by [mergen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33082/mergen/) with karma: 13 on 2018-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akshaywifi](https://answers.ros.org/users/53906/akshaywifi/) on 2020-07-26**:
nope .  this method does not work